# Why does Terraform detect security group in another VPC to the subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform plan works fine but when running `terraform apply` I get the following error:

> Security group sg-XXXXX and subnet subnet-Defaul1a belong to different
>   networks.

Here is the Terraform code that I'm trying to apply:

```
variable "region" {
  default = "eu-west-1"
}

variable "zones" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "eu-west-1a" = "euw1-az2"
    "eu-west-1b" = "euw1-az3"
    "eu-west-1c" = "euw1-az1"
  }
}

variable "default_kp" {
  type = "string"
  default = "ireland-dev-my_own_project-default-kp"
}

data "aws_ami" "ami_amazon" {
  name_regex = "^amzn2-ami-hvm"
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["137112412989"]

  filter {
    name   = "root-device-type"
    values = ["ebs"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "architecture"
    values = ["x86_64"]
  }
}

#   VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc" {
 cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
 enable_dns_hostnames = true
 enable_dns_support = true

 tags = {
   Name = "ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc"
   environment = "dev"
   application = "my_own_project-main"
 }
}

#   InternetGateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_ig" {
 vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc.id}"
}

#Public Subnet's
resource "aws_subnet" "ireland-dev-my_own_project-sn-pub-1a" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.10.0/24"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc.id}"
  availability_zone_id = "${var.zones.eu-west-1a}"
  tags = {
    Name = "ireland-dev-my_own_project-sn-pub-1a"
    environment = "dev"
    application = "my_own_project-main"
    finality = "publishing"
  }
}

#   Route Table
resource "aws_route_table" "ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_route_table" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc.id}"

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_ig.id}"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_route_table"
    environment = "dev"
    application = "my_own_project-main"
    finality = "publishing"
  }
}

#   Route Tables asotiation with Public Subnets
resource "aws_route_table_association" "ireland-dev-my_own_project-route_pub1a" {
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_route_table.id}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.ireland-dev-my_own_project-sn-pub-1a.id}"
}

#   Security Group's and Rules
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_local" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc.id}"
  description = "IP Cristian Sacristan Home"

  tags = {
    Name = "ireland-dev-my_own_project-sg-cs_local"
    env = "dev"
    application = "my_own_project-main"
    finality = "bastion"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sg-local-ssh-cs_home" {
  type = "ingress"
  from_port = 22
  to_port = 22
  protocol = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg_local.id}"
  cidr_blocks = ["8.8.8.8/32"] # MyIP
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg_bastion" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc.id}"
  description = "SG for bastion host"

  tags = {
    Name = "ireland-dev-my_own_project-sg-bastion"
    env = "dev"
    application = "my_own_project-main"
    finality = "bastion"
  }
}

#   Instances
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami = "${data.aws_ami.ami_amazon.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  availability_zone = "${aws_subnet.ireland-dev-my_own_project-sn-pub-1a.availability_zone}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.sg_local.id}","${aws_security_group.sg_bastion.id}"]
  key_name = "${var.default_kp}"
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  tags = {
    Name = "ireland-dev-my_own_project-ec2ins-bastion"
    env = "dev"
    application = "my_own_project-main"
    finality = "bastion"
  }
}
```

The full `apply` output:

```
aws_vpc.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc: Creating...
aws_vpc.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_vpc: Creation complete after 3s [id=vpc-AAAAAAAAAAAAA]
aws_internet_gateway.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_ig: Creating...
aws_subnet.ireland-dev-my_own_project-sn-pub-1a: Creating...
aws_security_group.sg_bastion: Creating...
aws_subnet.ireland-dev-my_own_project-sn-pub-1a: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-AAAAAAAAAAA]
aws_internet_gateway.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_ig: Creation complete after 1s [id=igw-AAAAAAAAAA]
aws_route_table.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_route_table: Creating...
aws_security_group.sg_local: Creation complete after 1s [id=sg-AAAAA]
aws_security_group_rule.sg-local-ssh-cs_home: Creating...
aws_security_group.sg_bastion: Creation complete after 1s [id=sg-AAAAAA]
aws_instance.bastion: Creating...
aws_route_table.ireland-dev-my_own_project-main_route_table: Creation complete after 1s [id=rtb-AAAAAAAA]
aws_route_table_association.ireland-dev-my_own_project-route_pub1a: Creating...
aws_security_group_rule.sg-local-ssh-cs_home: Creation complete after 1s [id=sgrule-AAAAA]
aws_route_table_association.ireland-dev-my_own_project-route_pub1a: Creation complete after 0s [id=rtbassoc-AAAA]

Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameter: Security group sg-AAAAAAAAAAAAA and subnet subnet-AA belong to different networks.
        status code: 400, request id: 6AAAAAA-AA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAA

  on main.tf line 135, in resource "aws_instance" "bastion":
 135: resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the subnet you want the instance to be in rather than the availability zone.

Because you specified `availability_zone` rather than `subnet_id` then Terraform has attempted to put the instance in a subnet that matches that AZ in the default VPC, not the VPC you are trying to place it in.

Unfortunately this is an issue with the fact that EC2 API allows for EC2 Classic (pre VPC) accounts with the default VPC for each region handling the default case where subnets are not specified.